# java jar no active profile set so java auto inactive error

Tags: java, spring-boot, build, jar

I run `java -jar C:\Users\LENOVO\IdeaProjects\support-learning-jp\build\libs\support-learning-jp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-plain.jar` so it run about 0.381s before auto inactive, i don't know why. I use java 19 .My application is spring boot rest Api.
[build.gradle.jar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oBawh.png)

i config jar file in build. Gradle like image but still not work.

i hope i can run jar and jar is not auto inactive.

```
23:35:04.965 [main] INFO com.example.supportlearningjp.SupportLearningJpApplication -- Starting SupportLearningJpApplication using Java 19.0.2 with PID 12932 (C:\Users\LENOVO\IdeaProjects\support-learning-jp\build\libs\support-learning-jp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-plain.jar started by LENOVO in C:\Users\LENOVO\IdeaProjects\support-learning-jp)
23:35:04.968 [main] INFO com.example.supportlearningjp.SupportLearningJpApplication -- No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
23:35:05.219 [main] INFO com.example.supportlearningjp.SupportLearningJpApplication -- Started SupportLearningJpApplication in 0.381 seconds (process running for 0.588)
```

this is result when i run

Comment: What do you mean with auto inactive? What do you expect and why? What happens and how is that different from your expectations? Also, please don't post images of code but instead use a [code block].

Comment: auto inactive is that jar will run and close after a while. I expect that i can fetch api when i run file jar.Now i can't fetch api because file jar closed after a while.

Comment: so i mean i want my jar file permanently run

Comment: file jar then now opens, but then not less then a second later, closes.

Answer (score -1):

The best way to get a clean and up-to-date build file is to use this: https://start.spring.io/

Choose either Gradle or Maven, add dependencies and generate your build file.

Add at least the Spring Boot Web dependency. Otherwise application will just run once and stop without doing anything.

Comment: Does that really answer the question above? This seems more like a comment.

Comment: @dan1stiscrying The Gradle file pasted as image by original poster is obviously wrong. My answer should help him generate and use the correct one.